# How Run Wordpress Theme with Netbeans?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, netbeans-8

Please I need some guides or tuto showing how *" run and import "* a Theme Based on **wordpress** in **Netbeans**.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The question is not clear, what do you want  ? Netbeans is an IDE and wordpress a CMS .. You want create a netbeans theme from wordpress or you want to install a theme on wordpress by netbeans ?

Comment: Thanks for reply
I have a wordpress theme(Template) I want run it using netbeans.

Comment: You can't just run a theme , you need to run site with Apache/mysql/php , install theme by wordpress interface. https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Themes

Comment: Ok thank you .
Ill try it @Fky

Answer (score 0):

You can edit a ***installed*** WordPress theme in Netbeans using the new project options.

> **(New Project-->PHP-->PHP Application from Remote Server)**

First, the theme must be installed on a webserver that supports mysql, php, and HTTPS. (https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/)